# Как сменить локаль чтобы Java увидела это?

Tags: windows-7, java-8, locale

В целях тестирования нужно изменить Локаль с RU на ENG, так чтобы код:

```
Locale.getDefault().getCountry()
```

Возвращал код англоязычной локали.
Менял Язык Системы с Русского на Английский как описано [тут](https://www.java.com/ru/download/help/locale.xml). Но не помогло. После смены и ребута все равно возвращает RU.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы может запустить java и указать нужную вам локаль в командной строке

```
java -Duser.language=en -Duser.country=US Main
```

Answer (score 0):

Нет, по ссылке - это кодировка для неюникодных программ. А надо тут менять:

[image: скриншот]